# How to pass both object and hashmap to model attribute in spring MVC so i can use them at the same time?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I am trying to create an "add Employee form" with basic attributes like name gender email etc which users can fill in

in the form, there will be a  drop down options for departments available where the list will be pre-populated by a linkedhashmap that will be sent over from the controller

I have already added an attribute object type "Employee" onto my model so when i fill in the form

and return to controller, the employee object will be set automatically

Controller.java

```
@GetMapping("/showFormForAdd")

public String showFormForAdd(Model theModel) {

    //fetch new list(if any) of departments added
    List<Department> theDepartments = departmentService.getDepartments();

    //Create a linkedhash map to hold our department_id-department name information
    final LinkedHashMap<Integer, String> departmentOptions = departmentService.generateDepartmentOptions(theDepartments);



    // create new employee object and attach to our model atrribute.

            //how to add multiple objects?? doing this so i can pre-populate available departments for selection
    theModel.addAttribute("employee", departmentOptions);


    Employee theEmployee = new Employee();
            //how to add multiple objects?? doing this so when program return control to controller it will help me set the attribute of employees so I can save it into the database
    theModel.addAttribute("employee", theEmployee);


    return "customer-form";
}
```

The problem:
How do i add multiple attributes for example, the employee object and the linkedhashmap onto my model so I can prepopulate the selection box and at the same time have methods available for my controller to set attributes for my employee object and save into my database when I return control to the controller?

any help will be appreciated..thanks!

EDIT:
just an update, every answer provided works..i was getting mixed up.

Comment: you are specifying the same key for departmentOptions & theEmployee.
use different keys.

Comment: Sorry could you provide me an example please? I’m quite new to this

Comment: i mean to say  theModel.addAttribute("options", departmentOptions); 
instead of  theModel.addAttribute("employee", departmentOptions);

Comment: I have tried this but how do I access the hashmap department attribute and make use of it in my JSP page? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using same key to add different object, use different key for different object
for example :

```
//use key "departmentOptions" for LinkedHashMap
theModel.addAttribute("departmentOptions", departmentOptions);

Employee theEmployee = new Employee();
//use key "employee" for employee object
theModel.addAttribute("employee", theEmployee);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correct(from your code's comment)

> //how to add multiple objects?? doing this so i can pre-populate
>   available departments for selection

You have to simply set different name for each object in your modelAttribute. In your code, you used same name twice, so the `departmentOptions` `employee` object  will be replaced by the later `employee` object. To overcome this, just set their unique name and you can send list of objects or different single type object like:

//adding multiple object to modelAttribute.

```
theModel.addAttribute("departmentOptions", departmentOptions);
Employee theEmployee = new Employee();         
theModel.addAttribute("employee", theEmployee);
-----
theModel.addAttribute("anotherObject", anotherObject);
```